# DateTime parse error in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

showing error when trying to get date from Sql server which is in the format like 1986-02-02 00:00:00.0000000. need to display in dd/MM/yyyy format. working fine with format like 2015-01-14.tried different ways but didn't work. pls help.

```
//c#
   string dt = reader[6].ToString();    
   dob_lbl.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

error:string was not recognised as a valid DateTime

Comment: No offense to you, but why in questions like this it is _always_ assumed that the `format` parameter of `DateTime.Parse(Exact)` is for the _output_ format? It is the _input_ format, the format that `dt` is in, which in your case obviously isn't `M/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Why do you store `datetimes` as `varchar?` If it's not a `varchar` but a `datetime` column you can simply use `reader.GetDateTime(6)` instead of `reader[6].ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

change this becuase your input string does not match the pattern that you are passing in to the parser

```
"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

to

```
"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss tt"
```

So like this

```
 dob_lbl.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: `tt` format specifier? o.O

Comment: And your format doesn't match OP's string.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get the data as recogniced sqlDateTime by using

```
DateTime dt = reader.GetDateTime(6);
```

Now `dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` should work.

Comment: There is no guarantee to get same result without any `IFormatProvider` because of `/` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

*Clearly*, your string and format doesn't match.

Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff` format instead when you parse `1986-02-02 00:00:00.0000000` string.

```
string s = "1986-02-02 00:00:00.0000000";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump(); // 02/02/1986
}
```

##But more important

I suspect you keep your `DateTime` values as characters. **Don't do that!** Use proper type always.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

If you keep your value a `datetime`, just use [`GetDateTime` metho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)d to get it as a `DateTime` and use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to get it's string representation.